# add new user in James

Tags: java, jakarta-mail, james

My question is simple. How can I create/add new user in James programmatically. I've been doing this making the use of Telnet. But I could not find the way of doing it in Java.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

James' users can also be created via JMX: see http://james.apache.org/server/3/manage-users.html#Manage_Users_via_JMX

Comment: Thanks for the response. By _programmatically_ I mean using Java. My client side asks to create a new account. And then, the server side would connect to James and create one if it's available. I think I wouldn't need a build-in Interface like jmanage.

Comment: @boburShox: For me using JMX means using Java and it is also the proper way of managing a remote server from a client application written in Java.

Comment: Well, actually, I haven't used it yet. But as API doc says, I will be able to do that. Thank you very much indeed!